# Dungeon crawler not working

Tags: c++

I am making a simple randomly generated dungeon crawler and when I ran it, sometimes the end or player weren't in the map, they were generated off map. After I fixed it I put limitations and checker to see if Player and End were created but now after I run it, it just gets stuck.

```
//Traps, Ending and Player generation
void TEPgen()
{
    srand(time(0));
    //Traps
    for(i=0; i<22; i++)
    {
        a=(rand()%11);
        b=(rand()%11);
        map[a][b]='T';

    }

    //Ending
    Egeneration:
        a=(rand()%11);
        b=(rand()%11);

        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
        if(((a+i)>9) && ((a-i)<0) && ((b+j)>9) && ((b-j)<0) )
        goto Egeneration;
        }
    }
    y=a;x=b;
    map[y][x]='E';

    //Player
    Pgeneration:
        a=(rand()%11);
        b=(rand()%11);

        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
        if(map[a+i][b+j]=='E' && map[a-i][b-j]=='E' && ((a+i)>9) && ((a-i)<0) && ((b+j)>9) && ((b-j)<0))
        goto Pgeneration;
        }
    }


    //Generation checker
    Gencheck:

        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(map[i][j]=='E')
                E+=1;
            else
            goto Egeneration;

            if(map[i][j]=='P')
                P+=1;
            else    
            goto Egeneration;
        }

    }



    next:
    map[a][b]='P';
    mapview();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but using labels and `goto` instead of real loops is a big no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other issues with your code, but the problem in your question is caused by the code under the `Gencheck` label. If you follow through the logic, is does (roughly) the following:

1. Loop through every cell in the map
2. If it is equal to 'E', then increment the E counter
3. If it is equal to 'P', then increment the P counter
4. If either of these tests fails, then go back to `Egeneration`

Hopefully this clarifies why your code enters an infinite loop: the cell is never equal to both 'E' and 'P' and so the program will always fail one of these two checks and go back to `Egeneration`.